# Scatterplot fill doesn't change in ggplot2 even when specified

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to assign a single color for all points on a scatter plot in ggplot2. However, no matter what color I set `fill =` to, the points always end up being black.

Here is my code (with dummy variables):

```
ggplot(data = testDF) +
    geom_point(aes(x = testDF$X, y = testDF$Y), 
    fill = "#2EC4B6", color = "#E71D36") # Fill is cyan, color is red
```

This is what the plot looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nRHo.png

Comment: When you define `data = testDF` you don't need to use `testDF$X` in the aesthetics. Just use `X` and `Y`. also `# Fill is cyan, color is red` what? Only color is important here.

Comment: @Masoud, The html code for the fill variable represents cyan while the html code for the color variable is red

Comment: I know that. I meant what the other users pointed out in their answers. In default only color is considered in `geom_point`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default shape used by `geom_point` does not have a `fill` aesthetic. You can address this by changing the `shape` parameter:

```
ggplot( mtcars, aes( x = wt, y = mpg ) ) +
    geom_point( shape = 21, fill = "#2EC4B6", color = "#E71D36" )
```

[image]

Comment: Another user already posted this before you. Just because they were lazy and did not post a graph, it is not fair to get upvotes and compete out their solution.

Comment: My apologies if I offended somebody. I just wanted to provide a high-quality answer. Feel free to upvote / accept the other answer.

Comment: This answer was higher quality; I didn't understand what the other one meant at first

Comment: I was on my mobile phone and my answer was a bit terse. The plot is a nice addition, and reminding us that both `pch` and `shape` can be used to modify the point style is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the dot style with `pch=21`. Default dot style does not use fill.

**EDIT** actual example:

```
ggplot(data = testDF) +
  geom_point(aes(x = X, y = Y),          # testDF has columns X and Y
  fill = "#2EC4B6", color = "#E71D36",   # Fill is cyan, color is red
  pch = 21)                              # point style that uses both color and fill
```

As @Artem pointed out, you can also use the `shape` aesthetic to change the dot style. I don't know exactly what the difference between `pch` and `shape` is, but I think `pch` is from older versions of `ggplot2`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the connection between `pch` and `shape`, @mikeck. Looking at `?aes`, it seems that `ggplot` understands the base R names like `pch` and `cex` but maps them to more "English-friendly" versions.